# ls ACL attributes impementation

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system, ls

I'm writing implementation of ls.

I've already done with attribute "@", but i have another problem.
How can i get is file has attribute "+" or not? Probably it's `tcgetattr`, but i can't exactly get how to take what i need.
Man is too small for this function and i didn't find there how to.
I just need to get True if there is attribute "+".

Also i found structure, which probably has the way to do this, but what i should compare?

```
struct termios {
    tcflag_t    c_iflag;    /* input flags */
    tcflag_t    c_oflag;    /* output flags */
    tcflag_t    c_cflag;    /* control flags */
    tcflag_t    c_lflag;    /* local flags */
    cc_t        c_cc[NCCS]; /* control chars */
    speed_t     c_ispeed;   /* input speed */
    speed_t     c_ospeed;   /* output speed */
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBP50.png)

Comment: first of all, no, `tcgetattr` is about **terminal (console, pseudotty for ssh, terminal emulator, modem etc) properties**. It is not at all what you want. Perhaps you should read [acl(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acl.5.html)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution in `# include <sys/acl.h>`, directly the `acl = acl_get_link_np(path, ACL_TYPE_EXTENDED);` function. If it isn't NULL - there is attribute. Don't forget to clean memory `acl_free(acl;)`